# How to type tilde (~) in R?

Tags: r

I need to write often down the tilde symbol in R, but I did not find anything useful browsing on the internet. I am using an Italian keyboard on a Linux OS.

Does some of you have any ideas?

Any hint or advises would be appreciated.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(35)`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/667622/italian-keyboard-entering-the-tilde-and-backtick-characters-without-cha

Comment: `ALT + 5` in Italian Keyboards for MAC OS, but I am not sure (Italian too but I have un UK keyboard), and `ALT + 126` for Windows user.

Comment: @Pascal, it's an Italian keyboard. There isn't on the keyboard, so I really don't know how can I do that. Some advice?

Comment: @SabDeM, thanks for the comment, but I'm on Linux OS and ALT+126 does not work!

Comment: @Quantopic - AltGr + ^ supposedly works on Linux according to my linked question.

Comment: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+Federico+Calboli+tilde#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20Federico%20Calboli%20tilde+page:1+mid:xawpm3stuyf4ro6z+state:results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this link over at Superuser:

https://superuser.com/questions/667622/italian-keyboard-entering-the-tilde-and-backtick-characters-without-cha

`AltGr + ^` will give you a tilde ~~~~ on a Linux system with an Italian keyboard, which is what you said you were using in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

```
(tilde <- rawToChar(as.raw(126)))
# [1] "~"
```

You could use this variable when you need tilde in text.

```
summary(lm(paste0("Sepal.Length", tilde, "Sepal.Width"), data=iris))
# Call:
# lm(formula = paste0("Sepal.Length", tilde, "Sepal.Width"), data = iris)
# 
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -1.5561 -0.6333 -0.1120  0.5579  2.2226 
# 
# Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   6.5262     0.4789   13.63   <2e-16 ***
# Sepal.Width  -0.2234     0.1551   -1.44    0.152    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.8251 on 148 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.01382, Adjusted R-squared:  0.007159 
# F-statistic: 2.074 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: 0.1519
```

Alternately, you could just type `tilde` and copy and paste the character.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is really genial, but I would like some more intituitive. Anyway, firstly +1 and, secondly, @latemail suggested a solution by using the keyboard directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Italian keyboard layout & also Linux OS then try `F5`.